# What is the proper way to preserve solder iron tips?

Tags: soldering

My question is should you turn off a solder iron to preserve tip when not in use. I am currently working on a project which requires sometimes a lot of soldering and sometimes occasional soldering to reroute wires or just tin wires to use as jumper cables. I work 8 to 12 hours a day and most of the time I am programming but sometimes I need to change things on hardware when I solder. So when I am programming should I turn off the soldering station or should I just leave it on or should I minimize the tempreture to preserve the solder tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the tip is hot, it is oxidizing faster. You should turn it off when not in use, but before it cools, apply some solder to the tip so it forms a cover around it when it cools. That prevents oxidation of the tip while it is cooling down and also when it is off.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn it off. I see several related questions. If you want to know more, you can look here:

[How to clean my soldering iron tip or how to determine that it's beyond repair?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/how-to-clean-my-soldering-iron-tip-or-how-to-determine-that-its-beyond-repair?rq=1)

A link from that thread I thought was good:
http://www.hakkousa.com/kb/attachments/How%20to%20maximize%20soldering%20iron%20tip%20life-GUIDe088627954984a4986039711460ec36a.pdf